# Convert HTML/CSS Variables into Tumblr Variables for Darkmode

Tags: javascript, css, variables, tumblr

Need help to turn HTML/CSS Variables into Tumblr Variables for the Javascript code for the dark/light mode.

**HTML/CSS Variable**

```
--mediumgreen: #7CA073;
--bgimage: url(/images/toplight.svg);
```

CSS will be:

```
color: var(--mediumgreen);
background-image: url(/images/toplight.svg);
```

Javascript will be:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color', '#fbfbfb')
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-image', 'url(/images/topdark2.svg')
```

**Tumblr Variable**

```
<meta name="color:mediumgreen" content="#7CA073" />
<meta name="image:bgimage" content="" />
```

and then the CSS will be:

```
color: {color:mediumgreen};
background-image: url("{image:bgimage}");
```

and then the Javascript will be:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('color', '#fbfbfb')
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tools-image', 'url(/images/tools2.png') //unchanged
```

***The properties with the standard property like 'color', 'background-color', and 'border-color' works fine but when it comes to image, I'm having trouble.

I tried this code below, but it's not working, I'm sure there's something wrong with first property.

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('{image:bgimage}', 'url({image:bgimage}')
```

Comment: `{image:bgimage}` isn't a valid style property

Comment: so i should use "background-image" on the property? but what if it's an image for a certain div and not the background-image for the whole website? I'm sorry for the dumb questions, I'm just starting out with this.

Comment: What does `name="image:bgimage"` evaluate to as a string, there will be a way to target it. Maybe you can share the url of your blog? bgimage is not a css property, so that might be part of the issue.